# Conditional Statements in Batch File

Tags: batch-file

I have written an MS DOS batch file that runs a series of commands.

Each command invokes a program with some specific parameters. To automate this, I combined all the commands.

The structure of the batch file is as shown below:

```
@echo off
if %1 == "b1" (
command 1
command 2
command 3
....
) else (
command a
command b
command c
)
```

I invoke it as shown below:

```
test.bat b1
```

If I pass b1 as an argument to the batch file, it will process the series of commands, command 1, command 2, command 3 and so on.

Similarly, if I want to execute the series of commands mentioned in the else section, I pass another argument:

```
test.bat abc
```

Since the argument passed to the batch file is not equal to b1, it will start executing the else section of the batch file. Here the argument I am passing (in this case, abc) is required by the commands, command a, command b, command c and so on as a parameter.

All this works pretty good.

However, the issue I am facing is, if I want to terminate the batch file in between (by pressing Ctrl + C), it does not prompt me with the option: Do you want to Terminate the Batch operation? Y/N

for instance, let us say, the batch file is processing the series of commands in the else section. Currently, assume that it is executing command a. If I press Ctrl + C, then instead of prompting me to cancel the operation it cancels the execution of command a and automatically proceeds with command b. If I press Ctrl + C again, it cancels command b and proceeds with command c and so on.

Now, on the other hand, if I write the batch file as shown below:

```
@echo off
command a
command b
command c
```

and I invoke it from command line as:

```
test.bat abc
```

Now, when I press Ctrl + C while the batch file is being executed, it prompts me to cancel the batch operation as expected.

It appears that when I add the conditional statement in the batch file, the functionality of Ctrl + C is modified in some way.

How can I fix this issue?

Thanks.

Comment: Click on the close window icon instead of pressing control C.  Or read the help from `CMD /?` to see if you can alter the Control C/Break handling.  It's possible that using `start "" /b /w command1` will work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I tried this and it seemed to work as expected:

```
@echo off
if "x%1x" == "xb1x" (
    echo yes it is
    dir
    ...
) else (
    echo no it is not
    dir
    ...
)
```

(where `...` repeats the previous pair of lines 100 times to give you time to press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>C</kbd>). I *did* get the prompt, even though the break occurred inside an `if` ... `else`.

So I suspect there's something unusual about the commands you're running, and the `if` behaviour is a red herring. In particular, as you say they are launching programs, I expect that the <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>C</kbd> gets passed directly to the program being run instead of to the batch file that launched it.

Comment: Thank you. Yes, it appears that the Ctrl + C is passed to the program I am invoking in the batch file instead of prompting me to Terminate the Batch Operation. So, it is specific to the program I am running.